# Php regex in variable

Tags: php, regex

**Regex:**
`/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"\d{1,3}\";/`

**String to match**
`priceSheet[1][1] = "30"; priceSheet[1][2] = "31";`

When I use

```
preg_match("/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"\d{1,3}\";/", $priceSheet, $matches);
```

it works, but

```
$min = `/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"\d{1,3}\";/`

preg_match($min, $priceSheet, $matches);
```

gives no result. Why is this? I am using php 7.0.

Edit: so the question is: why doesn't it work when I put the regex in a variable? It works when I use the regex as it is.

Comment: It appears that you are relying too heavily on PHP's variable string resolution in your function arguments.  Why not break them apart into functions, such that a function finds the minimum value, then another function does a match to accomplish the goal.  However the goal here is not clear.

Comment: https://eval.in/757694 Check it is working

Comment: $matches variable should contain your result. What does it contain?.
var_dump it or print_r it.

Comment: thanks for your answer! This was just an example code, what I really need is the number that comes after priceSheet[1][1] (or priceSheet[2][3], or any other digits).

Comment: @MaD , $matches contains 

    [0] => priceSheet[1][1] = "30"; 
for the first preg_match, for the second one $matches is empty.

Comment: You can match it with regular expression. preg_match_all("/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"\d{1,3}\";/", $priceSheet, $matches);. Which will give you
array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "priceSheet[1][1] = "30";" [1]=> string(24) "priceSheet[1][2] = "31";" }. It's just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your pattern to get only `priceSheet[1][1]`, adjust it to capture the number you want with `()`:

```
$min = "/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"(\d{1,3})\";/";    
$priceSheet = 'priceSheet[1][1] = "30"; priceSheet[1][2] = "31";';

preg_match($min, $priceSheet, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Then you want `$matches[1]`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => priceSheet[1][1] = "30";
    [1] => 30
)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I really only need to match priceSheet[1][1], but 
preg_match_all($min, $priceSheet, $matches);
doesn't work when I use the regex as provided in the example.

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` for matching all inputs.

```
<?php

$min = "/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"\d{1,3}\";/";
$priceSheet = 'priceSheet[1][1] = "30"; priceSheet[1][2] = "31";';
preg_match_all("/priceSheet\[\d\]\[\d\]\s*=\s*\"\d{1,3}\";/", $priceSheet, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => priceSheet[1][1] = "30";
            [1] => priceSheet[1][2] = "31";
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the other posters didn't bother to explain *why* you were having this trouble -- which was the actual question.

You were using:

```
||-------||----- escaped double quotes

$min = `/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"\d{1,3}\";/`

^---- back-ticks ------------------------^^---no semicolon
```

You should be using only single or double quotes on strings in php and not backticks.  Backticks are (off the top of my head) for mysql column names and shell commands.  When I tried to run your backticked line at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ it said:

> "**Warning**:  shell_exec() has been disabled for security
>   reasons..."

If you rewrap your regex pattern with double quotes, then everything will be sweet because the double quotes in the pattern are already escaped.

New code:

```
"$min = "/priceSheet\[1\]\[1\]\s=\s\"\d{1,3}\";/";
```

---

Next, I am wondering about a comment that you posted under AbraCadaver's answer.

> thanks, but I really only need to match priceSheet[1][1]

Does this mean you are only checking if that substring exists in the input string?  If this is true, then a regex solution is overkill, just use `strpos()` like this:

```
$priceSheet='priceSheet[1][1] = "30"; priceSheet[1][2] = "31";';
if(strpos($priceSheet,'priceSheet[1][1]')!==false){
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found";
}
// output: found
```

As a matter of best practice, always avoid using a regex solution when a non-regex string function can sensibly do the job.